# How do I pull counts of email sents to a specific smtp address

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I was asked to see if I could pull statistics on the volumne of email, and specifically the size of attachments sent from within my organization to a particular email address.

I work a lot with Exchange Web services but this seems like a more like a powershell through the Exchange shell type of situtation. Does anyone have any pointers on this? I am comfortable with powershell but I am not familiar with the Exchange cmdlets.

I also asked this question on server fault as I was not sure what site would be most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The first place I'd suggest trying to get this info from is the hub transport logs. Those only exist for 14 days by default so you may need to write a script that runs daily and exports the stats to a csv file or database.

If you need to get data older than 14 days right now then take a look at:
[Search-Mailbox](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298173.aspx)

Using the EWS approach many still be a viable route. Glen has been putting out some great stuff at:
[EWS Managed API and Powershell How-To series Part 1](http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/ews-managed-api-and-powershell-how-to.html)